# How to package hudson.war with extra plugins installed by default

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, hudson-api

I am wondering if it is possible to re-package the basic hudson.war with some extra plugins so they are installed by default for the end user.  If so, what is the process to do this?

I've got a hudson.war which I start up, and then I manually install the plugins that are needed.  Is there a way to reverse this process, and create a new hudson.war with the consequent files so that these plugins are installed by default?

Thank you,
-Denali

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could achieve this by adding your `.hpi` file into the `WEB-INF/plugins` folder of the hudson.war.

However, I don't think this is a clean approach.  Have you considered automating it somehow by using the Hudson cli for instance?

Eg.

```
java -jar hudson-cli.jar -s http://<hudson_url> install-plugin <your-plugin>.hpi
```